# Puppet cannot find epp template

Tags: puppet

I am attempting to use an EPP template in Puppet 6.2.0.

I have the following file /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/profile/manifests/linux/base/dns.pp :

```
class profile::linux::base::dns {
  file { '/etc/resolv.conf':
    path => '/etc/resolv.conf',
    ensure => file,
    owner => root,
    group => root,
    mode => 0644,
    content => epp('etc/resolv.conf.epp'),
}
```

The EPP template file is /etc/puppetlabs/code/modules/profile/templates/etc/resolv.conf.epp:

```
# This file is managed by Puppet. Manual modifications will be overridden.
domain <%= lookup('profile::linux::base::domainName') %>
```

However, the catalog does not compile with the error : 'Could not find template 'etc/resolv.conf.epp'

Why can this module not find the template, when it resides in the modules own template directory?

Answer (score 1):

Ah I worked it out now.  The epp call needs the module name in it:

```
content => epp('moduleName/file.epp')
```